# Why isn't my plugin script loaded in the backend?

Tags: wp-enqueue-style, wp-register-style

I've made a WP plugin that needs to load a script in the admin interface. This was working yesterday, but after updating it, it's no longer loading. I have the following code in my `functions.php`:

```
define('STENT_PLUGIN_URL',plugins_url('', __FILE__ ));    
add_action('after_setup_theme','stent_setup');

function stent_setup() {
    (...)
    add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', 'stent_load_admin_scripts' );
}

function stent_load_admin_scripts() {
    var_dump(STENT_PLUGIN_URL); // Debugging to see that I get this far

    wp_register_script('stent-extended-js', STENT_PLUGIN_URL . '/js/stent-extended.js');
    wp_enqueue_style('stent-extended-js');

    wp_register_style('stent-admin-css', STENT_PLUGIN_URL . '/css/stent-admin.css');
    wp_enqueue_style('stent-admin-css');
}
```

In my `stent-extended.js`I have the following code for testing purposes:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    console.log('TEST');
});
```

The link to the script / css is correct (I've tested it), but for some reason it is not added into the queue or loaded. I have disabled all other plugins I'm using while debugging.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you have accidentally typed:

```
wp_enqueue_style('stent-extended-js');
```

instead of

```
wp_enqueue_script( 'stent-extended-js' );
```

so that could explain why it's not properly enqueued.

Comment: *face palm* - did anyone say code blindness? :-D

Comment: it happens to the best of us ;-) Good luck wit the  project @Steven